# Accessing C-Code analyser from within C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, static-analysis

I am developing a visual studio C# application.

As part of this application I want to conduct a static analysis of C-Code (i.e. the C# application analyzes C-Code).

To this end I want to access some static code analysis tool from within my C#-code and run it over the relevant C-Files.

I hoped that there was some API for "CppCheck", which is installed as a plugin in my Visual Studio Environment:

[image]

However, so far I have not found an API through which I would be able to access CppCheck.

My question is: Does anyone know an API for CppCheck or some other C-Code-Analyser that I can use within my C# application?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use The [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) API from your C# code, a demo project CppDepend.PowerTools is delivered in the install to show you how to do it.

Comment: Unfortuately, I can only use open source tools